# SharePoint 2010 REST - Multiple Checkbox Select - Set via Jquery/REST

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, rest, jquery, sharepoint-rest-api

Good morning, I'm trying to set a multiple select (checkbox) SharePoint item via  bootstrap form independent of SharePoint's forms.  I can get everything to work except passing the joined checkbox values to the SharePoint list item via REST.

```
    <div class="form-group" id="Point-Tags-FG">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="chkA" value="1">1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="chkB" value="2">2</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="chkC" value="3">3</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    var url = ".../ListName";
    var event = $("#Event-Type").val();
    var date = $("#Event-Date-Time").val();
    var address = $("#Point-Address").val();
    var latitude = $("#Point-Latitude").val();
    var longitude = $("#Point-Longitude").val();
    var description = $("#Point-Description").val();

    var tags = []; 
    if ($('input[name="chkA"]').is(':checked')) {
        tags.push("1");
    }
    if ($('input[name="chkB"]').is(':checked')) {
        tags.push("2");
    }
    if ($('input[name="chkC"]').is(':checked')) {
        tags.push("3");
    }

    var SpecialTags = {"__metadata":{"type":"Collection(Edm.String)"},"results":[tags.join(',')]};

    var info = {
        __metadata: {type: "SP.Data.ListName"},
        PostId: post,
        EventValue: event,
        Date: date,
        Address: address,
        Latitude: latitude,
        Longitude: longitude,
        Description: description,
        Tags: SpecialTags
    };

    var body = JSON.stringify(info);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        processData: false,
        data: body,
        error: function (err) {console.log(err)},
        success: function (data) {
            alert(Entry Submitted.');               
            location.reload();
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately, every time the function is submitted it results in a console error POST URL 400 (Bad Request).  I've looked around at some other examples here and can GET the information I just can't seem to POST it via 2010 which I'm stuck using for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json value of multi-choice field value in the provided example is specified properly but not the `Content Type` header.

Since you are passing metadata tag, the *valid* Content Type header should be `application/json;odata=verbose`. Another supported content types are:

- `accept: application/json; odata=minimalmetadata`   //minimalmetadata
- `accept: application/json; odata=nometadata` //nometadata

Follow [this article](https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2014/08/13/json-light-support-rest-sharepoint-api-released/) for a more details.

You could also get more information about error by specifying for example, *error callback* for [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
error: function( jqXHR, textStatus){
     console.log(jqXHR.responseText); 
}
```